# React Button Click should change the display value of div

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I got a Navbar which has a button do change the display value of a login form. The Login form and the Login form is a diffrent file, the navbar is a diffrent file and the homepage where it should be display is a diffrent file. Those are the minimal variants of each so that you got some got to understand my problem in detail:

Homepage:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Login />
            <div id="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Navbar:

```
const Navbar= () => {

    const showLogin = () => {
        document.getElementById('Login').style.display='block';
    }

  return (
    <div id="Navbar">
        <NavLink activeClassName="active" to='/'><img src={logo}/></NavLink>
        <ul>
            ...
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <button onClick={showLogin}>Anmelden</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Login-Form:

```
const Login = () => {
    return (

            <div id="Login">
                <form>
                    <label>Anmelden</label>
                    <label for="username">Nutzername</label>
                    <input name="username" type="text"></input>
                    <label for="pw">Passwort</label>
                    <input name="pw" type="password"></input>
                    <button type="submit">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
    );
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this, or would my easiest option be to include the Login source code into the Navbar source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to move your Login component inside Navbar. Keep it as it is.
You can use `useState` and `Props` to switch css classes to show/hide your **Login** component. I have created very simple solution for you in this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-ritchie-53w057?file=/src/Navbar.js).

*Steps:*

1. Create two CSS classes `hidden` and `block`
2. In your Login component add a boolean prop which switches class `hidden` to `block` if true.
3. Create a prop for `onClick` in the Login component.
4. Create a `useState` inside your Homepage which holds a boolean value. That boolean value pass it to the Login page prop and then use `onClick` prop from Navbar to switch that boolean state

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on your CSS system this is easily achievable just by using that.

The React solution is using [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).
The easy way is to create a `ref` in the parent component and then pass it down as a prop to both components:

- In Homepage (i.e. parent), create a ref like so `loginRef = useRef();` then pass it down as a prop to the 2 children.
- In `Login-Form.js` you assign that prop on the div with id Login like so `<div id='Login' ref={props.loginRef}>`
- Then in `Navbar.js` you can use that prop to change its display value like so  const `showLogin = () => {props.loginRef.current.style.display='block';}`

NB: This is a fast and easy way, not best practice but it gets the work done. The best-practice here is to use [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) and - super advanced - [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle). Take your time and go through the documentation when you're ready.

Answer (score 0):

Login page will show "it is not active" first because active is set to false.but once you click on submit button it will show "it is active"

HomePage

```
const HomePage = () => {
    const[active,setActive]=useState(false);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar activesetter={setActive} />
            <Login activestatus={active} />
            <div id="content">
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Login

```
const Login = (props) => {

    return(
    <div>
        <div>
        {props.activestatus ? "it is active" : "it is not active" }
        </div>
    </div>

    );

}
```

Navbar

```
const Navbar = (props) => {
    const handleSubmit=(e)=> {
            e.preventDefault();
            props.activesetter(true);
        
    }
    return(
    <div>
        <form  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <button  type="submit">Login</button>

        </form>
    </div>

    );

}
```